# Equivalent AmEnglish expression of BrEnglish slang term "cheeky"

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english, british-english, slang

I play an online game with a group of people, one of whom is UK-based. He was going out of town for several days, so he told us to "feel free to do a cheeky quest" without him.

What does the word "cheeky" mean in that context? I tried to look it up, but none of the meanings I found - even on urbandictionary - seemed to fit. My best guess is that it means something like "quick"?  How would I express something similar in American English?

Comment: I would consider the likelihood that he misspelled the word, or otherwise typed something other than what he intended.

Comment: @HotLicks I wondered this as well, but upon further investigation he confirmed the usage of the word.

Comment: Traditionally it means 'impudent', but the modern meaning in the UK among the Banter Generation is more 'impromptu' or 'spontaneous', with a hint of the 'unauthorised'.

Comment: @JHCL  I think that might be more toward what this individual was trying to express with his usage of the word.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I think it's a combination of the traditional meaning of cheeky, meaning amusingly sassy, with the idea of the event being unplanned and not the thing you were meant to be doing, as in a "cheeky pint." Maybe there is also an added layer of speed too, as you suggest.

See this blog post about "cheeky Nando's." https://britishisms.wordpress.com/2015/05/27/cheeky-nandos/

I don't think such an equivalent exists in American English.

Comment: A generation of British youth has taken up the old term ['banter'](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=banter) to mean a particular kind of knowing, playful, largely meme-based teasing. The 'cheeky Nando's' phenomenon is part of that, and thereby a number of 'cheeky' usages.

Answer (score 2):

Norman Schur, Eugene Ehrlich & Richard Ehrlich, *British English A to Zed*, third edition (2007) has this entry for *cheeky*:

> **cheeky,** *adj.* Very impudent and disrespectful in speech or behavior.

But *impudent* in the sense of "cocky boldness" (as *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* puts it) isn't necessarily a simple matter of regrettable rudeness or disrespectfulness, and I can imagine *cheeky*, in this same sense, implying (as Rick Deckard suggests in another answer) a kind of free-spirited sassiness that is actually charming and even admirable.

So perhaps either *sassy* or *impudent* might convey the sense that your British friend had in mind.